# Passing table contents from SQL to HTML through Python and Jinja

Tags: python, html, sql, html-table, jinja2

I have a table in a database on phpLiteAdmin working on SQL and I'm trying to get that table through Python and then sending it to render in HTML where I want to add these columns and rows into a table. What I did was I SELECTED that column of that table and put it in a variable as such:
`symbols = db.execute("SELECT symbol FROM table")`
what I'm gettin is something like this:
`symbols = ['symbol':'item1','symbol':'item2'...]`

and I'm sending it to HTML via python and then using Jinja I'm doing a for loop to print them in a table.. But I want to be able to print each element of that column at a time.. 
when I use the:

```
<td>{% for symbol in symbols %}
{{symbol["symbol"]}}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

it prints all the elements in symbols.. but I want to print only 1 and then later after inserting the other columns I want to print the second and then third element..etc
what I get is either:
`{'symbol': 'item1'} {'symbol': 'item2'} ...`
or
`item1 item2 ...`
what I want is to print first just:
`item1`
and then after I do the same for the other columns I want to print `item2`
I tried everything I know and I tried to find a way to break out of the loop but I'm not getting the result I want; couldn't find any link or tip concerning this particular issue... is it doable? if so how can I implement it?
P.S: this is my first time posting here.. so I'm still kind of new to this thing :)

Comment: "I tried everything". Right, okay... What is everything? Can you provide some examples.

Comment: Lists and dicts are not the same. You need to be specific about what you have. The sample you give is not valid as either.

Comment: @daniel you're right, my bad.. I fixed the question

Comment: @david well I tried everything I know is what I meant to say and I've been looking for answers since yesterday..

Comment: You haven't fixed it, that's still invalid. Please show the real content of `symbols`.

Comment: @daniel it's a table on SQL with a column called symbol and in that column there are stock symbols 'AAPL' 'NFLX' ...

Comment: Please post what actually comes out when you do that `db.execute`. What you have posted cannot possibly be what you are getting, since it is invalid syntax.

Comment: after the db.execute and after this HTML render
`{% for i in symbols %
}<td>{{i.symbol}}</td>
{% endfor %}`

I'm getting this output on the page:
AAPL NFLX

Comment: @DanielRoseman with the:
`<td>{% for symbol in symbols %}
i{{symbol}}</td>
{% endfor %}`
I was getting this:
`{'symbol': 'AAPL'} {'symbol': 'NFLX'}`

Answer (score 0):

If your data like this, `symbols = ['item1','item2','item2',..]` then,

```
{% for symbol in symbols %}
<td>{{symbol}}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

And if your data is like `symbols = ['symbol':'item1']`, Then,

```
{% for i in symbols %}
<td>{{i.symbol}}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried that actually and the output was {'symbol': 'item1'}.. I also tried to put symbol["symbol"].. but it printed all the items again like item1 item2 ... is there a way to stop the for loop after 1 iteration?

Answer (score 0):

As I've said in the comments, you should be specific about the actual format of the data you are getting; once you've done so, the solution becomes much clearer.

As far as I can tell, your db interface is giving you back a list of dictionaries. So you can iterate through that list, and in each iteration access the dictionary key you want:

```
{% for symbol in symbols %}
    <td>{{ symbol['symbol'] }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I just tried that still getting the same result .. it's returning all the rows in that column but I just want to print one at a time

Comment: I don't have the slightest idea what you mean here. Obviously a loop will loop through whatever you give it, what else did you expect?

Comment: I was wondering if there's a way to break out of the loop or just stop it after a certain iteration.

Comment: No, and I can't work out why you would want to. If you have other columns to display, why are you querying them separately? Your view should build up the data you want to display in a format suitable for displaying it, and your template should then just iterate through and show the data.

Comment: should I query all the columns at the same time? Should I just select table or all the columns in one query and then iterate over the table in HTML?

Comment: well I tried what you said... but now it displays the table as such:
`{'price': 135.72, 'symbol': 'AAPL', 'shares': 1.0, 'date': 'Mon Feb 20 07:15:06 2017', 'name': 'Apple Inc.'}
{'price': 142.22, 'symbol': 'NFLX', 'shares': 1.0, 'date': 'Mon Feb 20 07:58:31 2017', 'name': 'Netflix, Inc.'}`
how can I at least remove the name of the column?